# Build default groups with Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a `User` and a `Group` model (user has_many groups). When a new `User` is created I want to build three default `groups` for that user. Lets call them `x`, `y` and `z` (which would be the `name`).

I guess `Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc` is the right tool for this job. Correct? How can I use it to create the groups in the `create` function?

**web/controllers/user_controller.ex**

```elixir
[...]
def create(conn, %{"user" => user_params}) do
  changeset = User.changeset(%User{}, user_params)

  case Repo.insert(changeset) do
    {:ok, user} ->
      conn
      |> MyApp.Auth.login(user)
      |> put_flash(:info, "User created successfully.")
      |> redirect(to: user_path(conn, :show, user))
    {:error, changeset} ->
      render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
  end
end
[...]
```

**web/models/user.ex**

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.User do
  use MyApp.Web, :model
  use Arc.Ecto.Model

  schema "users" do
    field :first_name, :string
    field :last_name, :string

    has_many :groups, MyApp.Group
[...]
```

**web/models/group.ex**

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.Group do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  schema "groups" do
    field :name, :string

    belongs_to :user, MyApp.User
[...]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a list of the new groups:

```
groups =
  for name <- ~w(x y z) do
    Group.changeset(%Group{}, %{name: name})
  end
```

Then, use `Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc/2` to add them to the `:groups` association of the User changeset:

```
changeset =
  User.changeset(%User{}, user_params)
  |> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:groups, groups)
```

A normal `Repo.insert(changeset)` should insert everything with proper assocations now.